# How do I run a camel timer immediately and subsequently at a fixed time?

Tags: apache-camel

It seems very easy to do either one or the other, but not both.
Any ideas? It seems it cannot be done with a Timer, or CronScheduledRoutePolicy.
Can it be done programmatically?
I would add further information, but I'm not sure what else really is needed. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

yes you can do both, see https://camel.apache.org/timer.html

- `delay` parameter for the FIRST delay in milliseconds, you set it to 0
- `period` in milliseconds for all other invocations

ie: `timer://mytimer?fixedRate=true&delay=0&period=10000` will wait 0ms for the first event, 10000ms for all other events

Comment: thanks Paizo, but I need to run the timer immediately and then at a fixed time e.g. immediately, then at 1700 every day. I think What you have said above will run it immediately and then at a fixed interval, which is not the same thing.

Comment: then with `pattern` instead of period you should be fine, set the pattern for the daily event and keep the delay for the first event?

Comment: On "delay" it says "The number of milliseconds to wait before the first event is generated. Should not be used in conjunction with the time option."  But the pattern option is used with the time option. So you can't use the delay, pattern and time options together (unless the text is wrong).  Where I'm currently going is defining a route dynamically in java.

Answer (score 2):

look at using the [quartz2 camel component](http://camel.apache.org/quartz2.html).

You can set `fireNow` to `true` and then provide a cron pattern for your desired schedule.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I am trying now but I am getting "No component found with scheme: quartz2" despite having included the dependency on camel-quartz2 in the POM. Any ideas?

Comment: `mvn clean install?`